# Deployment fails every time

Tags: node.js

I have gone through all the Heroku troubleshooting steps with no joy... My console shows the following.

```
git push heroku master    
Enumerating objects: 569, done.
Counting objects: 100% (569/569), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (557/557), done.
Writing objects: 100% (569/569), 530.35 KiB | 5.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 569 (delta 379), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.0.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.2
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.0.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.0.0...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 6.14.2 (replacing 6.9.0)...
remote:        npm 6.14.2 installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/build_1291b113e4253c20dec49dcf5ededdbe/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build_1291b113e4253c20dec49dcf5ededdbe/node_modules/fsevents
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild
remote:        
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_1291b113e4253c20dec49dcf5ededdbe/node_modules/fsevents/build'
remote:          SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
remote:          COPY Release/.node
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_1291b113e4253c20dec49dcf5ededdbe/node_modules/fsevents/build'
remote:        
remote:        > core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /tmp/build_1291b113e4253c20dec49dcf5ededdbe/node_modules/core-js
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:        
remote:        added 1600 packages in 23.237s
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > craft-frontend@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_1291b113e4253c20dec49dcf5ededdbe
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:        
remote:        ./src/App.js
remote:        Cannot find file './components/SelectedBrewery' in './src'.
remote:        
remote:        
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! craft-frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the craft-frontend@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.IYfLg/_logs/2020-04-15T19_00_54_116Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to craft-brew.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/craft-brew.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/craft-brew.git'
```

this is what is confusing.

```
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:        
remote:        ./src/App.js
remote:        Cannot find file './components/SelectedBrewery' in './src'.
```

It is failing to find a file that IS there. My app works in my local env and that file certainly exists. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.